# Why does Apple allow factory reset if passcode is forgotten?

Tags: password, screen-lock, activation-lock, restart

I just came across the instructions to factory reset Apple device if one does not remember the device passcode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

I am very new to Apple and I don't understand how come Apple allows such a thing. What if someone stole my device and wants to clean the device before selling it? Should the iTunes on the connected computer be logged in with the same Apple ID as the locked device? Is that what would prevent a thief from cleaning a stolen device? Would the above instructions work if the iCloud account on the device is locked as well?

Comment: Questions asking how/why Apple does <some thing XYZ> are typically not allowed here and are subject to being closed or deleted.

Comment: Anyway, the question in the title is based on a wrong assumption. The answer to the linked Q explains why a reset is not possible while Activation Lock is in place.

Comment: You looked at a question from 2013, about an iPhone 4. An iPhone 4 was a lot less secure than any iPhone you could buy today. The other link is for the case that you backed up your iPhone to _your_ computer. It doesn't help a thief who steals your phone but hasn't got your computer.